# Telerik After Update from 2015.1.401.45 to 2020.2.512.45 Getting Errors

Tags: telerik

I am using Telerik Ajax in Old Web forms project.
After the update, I start to get errors from everywhere.
It wondering, maybe I just need to update something else in order to get it to work ???

Errors like :

```
Uncaught Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: The script tag registered for type 'System.Web.UI.Page' and key 'ctl00$RadCodeBlock1' has invalid characters outside of the script tags:...
```

Comment: I would suggest you to set the "EnablePageHeadUpdate" property of the main RadAjaxManager to "false" and see how it goes. If there is some CSS move it to the head part of the page. 
Greetings!

Comment: What about Jquery, my current code use v1.11.3

Comment: Have you tried to set the EnablePageHeadUpdate to false?

Comment: I am not aware of jQuery issues related to this error. It might be worth it to test with the latest version of Telerik UI fo Asp.Net Ajax.

Comment: yes i did, it not help, i have other major issue , can not upload file it throw me error :

Comment: [CryptographicException: The cryptographic operation has failed!]

Comment: Check this article https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/knowledge-base/asyncupload-the-cryptographic-operation-has-failed-error-after-upgrade

Comment: Rumen Jenkov, your post fix on of my issue, make it as an answer and I will vote it as correct answer

Comment: I don't have the upload issue, but I tried the `EnablePageHeadUpdate = False` fix, and that did not help my `Invalid characters` error either.

Comment: I am having this same error after upgrading from a 2013 version, but it seems to be tied specifically to the Ajax controls, because if i set `EnabledAjax = false`, then it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

To fix the reported error follow the instructions in this dedicated help article https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/knowledge-base/asyncupload-the-cryptographic-operation-has-failed-error-after-upgrade.

On a side note, it is a very good decision to upgrade to the 2020.2.512 version since it is very stable and secure.

Best,
Rumen